# Transforming Function Bodies within Boost Phoenix Expressions

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-phoenix, boost-proto

How can I also include function bodies in a transformation of a Boost Phoenix expression?

For example, I have built on the Lazy Functions section of the [Boost Phoenix Starter Kit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit.html#phoenix.starter_kit.lazy_functions), and created a lazy addition function:

```
struct my_lazy_add_impl {
  typedef int result_type;
  template <typename T>
  T operator()(T x, T y) const { return x+y; }
};
phoenix::function<my_lazy_add_impl> my_add;
```

I then prepare a simple plus-to-minus transform from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077637/transforming-a-boost-c-phoenix-expression-tree), shown here:

```
struct invrt:
  proto::or_<
    proto::when<
      proto::plus<proto::_, proto::_>,
      proto::functional::make_expr<proto::tag::minus>(
        invrt(proto::_left), invrt(proto::_right)
      )
    >,
    proto::otherwise<
      proto::nary_expr<proto::_, proto::vararg<invrt> >
    >
  >
{};
```

However, when I apply an inverted Phoenix `lambda` expression, using `my_add`, to its arguments, as shown below, it seems the intended inversion has not been achieved. Is there a recommended way to implement function calls within Phoenix, which can facilitate such transformations?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto f =         phoenix::lambda(_a = 0)[my_add(_1,_2)];
  auto g = invrt()(phoenix::lambda(_a = 0)[my_add(_1,_2)]);
  std::cout << f()(1,2) << std::endl; // 3
  std::cout << g()(1,2) << std::endl; // 3 again; alas not -1
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is really very simple and you're going to kick yourself. The expression transformation you wrote knows how to convert a plus *node* into a subtract *node*. But there is no plus node in the expression you're passing to it. Look again:

```
auto g = invrt()(phoenix::lambda(_a = 0)[my_add(_1,_2)]);
```

Where's the plus node? To Proto (and to Phoenix), `my_add` is opaque. They don't know there's an addition going on inside there. How could they?

**====EDIT====**

Consider this instead, which does what you intend:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/proto/proto.hpp>
namespace proto = boost::proto;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;
using namespace phoenix::arg_names;
using namespace phoenix::local_names;

auto const my_add = phoenix::let(_a = _1, _b = _2)[_a + _b];

struct invrt:
  proto::or_<
    proto::when<
      proto::plus<proto::_, proto::_>,
      proto::functional::make_expr<proto::tag::minus>(
        invrt(proto::_left), invrt(proto::_right)
      )
    >,
    proto::otherwise<
      proto::nary_expr<proto::_, proto::vararg<invrt> >
    >
  >
{};

int main()
{
  auto f =         phoenix::lambda(_a = 0)[my_add(_1,_2)];
  auto g = invrt()(phoenix::lambda(_a = 0)[my_add(_1,_2)]);

  std::cout << f()(1,2) << std::endl; // 3
  std::cout << g()(1,2) << std::endl; // -1, w00t!
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. I had guessed this was the way to do it, but wanted some reassurance before building on the idea.

Comment: p.s. I guess the `let` body could also be `_1 + _2`.

Comment: I /think/ you'll find that in more complicated contexts that you'll need to create a new scope for your function bodies; hence the `let`. At least, I seem to recall learning this lesson the hard way, but for the life of me, I can no longer remember why. :-P

Comment: Yes, I had the same feeling; why not just use `sequence` (?), as in: `auto const f2 = (stmt1,stmt2);`. I was leaning towards `lambda` over `let` but I am surprised now to see that my main reason for using scopes, that they will *return* the value of their last "statement", is also true of `sequence`. Hmm. Thanks again, I'll trust your judgement and go with scopes for the moment.

Comment: Then again, in favour of scopes, local variables are nice sometimes :)